# Are there any good books on the history of condensed matter?

Tags: physics, book-recommendation, solid-state-physics

Condensed matter is probably as impactful as quantum mechanics, but has less coverage in popular media than other branches like particle physics. Condensed matter experiments have led to many Nobel prizes including the discovery of quantum mechanics by black body radiation. Is there are any good book on the history of solid state/condensed matter from a physics perspective? Most books out there that claim to be such end up as books about technology and engineering.

Answer (score 5):

While is not a general history of condensed matter physics, [Out of the Chrystal Maze: Chapters from The History of Solid State Physics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019505329X) is a history of solid state physics.

Comment: Great find! I will take a look.